# When I create an email alias in Gmail does Gmail take ownership of the email server?

Tags: gmail, imap

I'm trying to better understand the relationship between IMAP and Gmail aliases.

Below is a common scenario a lot of people are using to setup a custom email domain inside the Gmail web-client.

1. I have a website named example.com
2. The MX records for example.com point to mailgun.org (Mailgun is a popular email service)
3. Mailgun is setup to *foward* all emails from hello@example.com to mypersonalemail@gmail.com
4. Inside Gmail an *Alias* is created so that the web-client for mypersonalemail@gmail.com can also send and receive email using hello@example.com

Based on this scenario... is Gmail the email server for hello@example.com?

And most importantly, if I need the IMAP logins and passwords for hello@example.com to use in another 3rd party application, do I just use the logins and passwords for mypersonalemail@gmail.com?

Comment: "is Gmail the email server for hello@example.com": From the sender's perspective no (because it uses mailgun.org), from the receiver's perspective yes.

Comment: @Robert mailgun.org does not host any POP/IMAP email servers, all they do is forward along the emails. So i assumed it was Gmail who was running the email server in this case, yes? Also what IMAP auth settings do I use?

Comment: How should a sender of an email know that? If you send a mail you deliver it to the specified SMTP server. If that server forwards it is of no concern to the sender.

Answer (score 2):

> Based on this scenario... is Gmail the email server for hello@example.com?

It's unclear how you define "the mail server" here – the idea of "*the* server" for a given mailbox can be a bit fuzzy (especially when forwarding or automated fetching is involved), and it wouldn't be unusual for the same mailbox's different tasks to be spread across different servers.

*(Indeed, even though you think of "Gmail" as a single unit, internally it consists of hundreds of servers, some of them receiving mail via SMTP, some of them storing it, some of them serving web or IMAP.)*

So from the mailbox user's perspective, yes, Gmail is "the server"... but as far as message delivery between domains goes, it's a definite "no".

> Based on this scenario... is Gmail the email server for hello@example.com?

Yes, because you use Gmail as the primary storage for messages sent to this mailbox.

> Based on this scenario... is Gmail the email server for hello@example.com?

No, because the MX records of `example.com` do not point to Gmail – they point to Mailgun.

It doesn't matter to your senders that Mailgun doesn't store the messages, as they *only* deal directly with what's listed in your MX records.

> Based on this scenario... is Gmail the email server for hello@example.com?

No, because the "Alias" configuration doesn't actually make it *accept* mail for this address.

This only works because in your step 3, Mailgun rewrites the original SMTP envelope recipient to become your Gmail address. If you tried to bypass Mailgun and pointed your MX directly at Gmail, the messages (with their original `RCPT TO:<hello@example.com>` envelope) would be rejected.

In Gmail, you only use an "alias" to *send* messages from some external address. (But note that 'aliases' in Gmail have a different purpose from what some other mail providers use the term 'alias' for.)

> And most importantly, if I need the IMAP logins and passwords for hello@example.com to use in another 3rd party application, do I just use the logins and passwords for mypersonalemail@gmail.com?

Yes. Your IMAP credentials directly correspond to the Gmail website credentials. Since you're receiving the messages when you're signed in to the 'mypersonalemail@gmail.com' account, you need to use the same for IMAP.